# How to create an object without invoking its constructor?

Tags: java

Is it possible to create an object reference without invoking its constructor? For example, I have a main class that initializes a bunch of things in the constructor. In doing so, I've also created some getter methods in order to access some of the variables in this main class.

The problem is that in my other class when I create a new instance of the object it runs the constructor again. I only want a reference to the class so I can use the getter methods in it.

Comment: It sounds like either your getters should really be static methods, or your class should be a singleton.

Comment: I'd like to see the code that accompanies this. What "other class". And how is it exactly that this is a problem? "create a new instance of the object" => constructing an object => constructor being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you should use static methods.

```
public class MyClass{
 private static int x;

 public static int getX(){
  return x;
 }
}
```

Now to reach x, you should use `MyClass.getX();`

Comment: I didn't even think of using static methods. Thanks a million. Just what I was looking for.